# Temps après « je pensais que »

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, concordance-des-temps

Cette question concerne le temps utilisé après la formulation « je pensais que ». Je me rends compte que j'utilise cette expression assez souvent et je me demande si « je pensais que » suit les règles de paroles rapportées. Un exemple pour clarifier les choses:

> A: pourquoi tu n'as pas amené un parapluie avec toi?
>
> moi: je pensais qu'il va pas pleuvoir...

Dans l'exemple dessus, je ne suis pas sûr quel temps utiliser pour la partie après « je pensais que ». Je vois deux possibilités:

- *qu'il allait pas pleuvoir*
- *qu'il va pas pleuvoir*

La tendance pour moi est d'utiliser « va pas pleuvoir » simplement parce que ça me prend pas la tête pour conjuguer haha.

Deuxièmement pour les francophones: est-ce que cette formulation vous perturbe beaucoup? Si non je vais pas faire trop attention sur cet aspect minuscule parce que l'important pour moi est de paraître naturel lol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dans ce cas-ci, pour respecter la concordance des temps (postériorité par rapport à un verbe à l'indicatif imparfait), il faut dire

> je pensais qu'il n'allait pas pleuvoir

ou

> je pensais qu'il ne pleuvrait pas

"Je pensais qu'il ne va pas pleuvoir" est incorrect et "sonne" effectivement mal aux oreilles. Un locuteur natif francophone ne fera (généralement) pas cette faute et si vous la faites... j'ai bien peur que cela trahisse que le français n'est pas votre langue maternelle.